# Programming puzzle: volume of liquid in a container with partitions

Tags: puzzle

One of my friends was asked the following problem in an interview:

Consider a rectangular container with several thin partitions. The cross-section of the container looks like the following:

```
        |
    |   |                   
|   |   |   |           |      
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

The heights of the partitions are {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2}

Now you fill the container with some liquid.

The problem is to algorithmically determine the total volume of the liquid in the container. Assume unit depth and unit gap between any two partitions, so that numerically the area and the volume are equal.

Input: An array of the thin partition heights: h

In the above example, the total volume of liquid is 13 units.

```
2 units between h1 and h2,
3 units between h2 and h3,
2 units between h3 and h4,
6 units between h4 and h7
```

Also check that for the following example, the volume is 18 units

```
        |
    |   |           |       
|   |   |   |       |   |   |   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

The heights of the partitions are {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.  If you mean to ask us to write a solution to the problem then your question is far too broad to be in-scope here.

Comment: "6 units between h4 and h7 " ? looks like 5 to me. Maybe instead of "In the above example" you meant: "In the example below" ?

Comment: No, "6 units between h4 and h7" is for the first figure.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just write it out. Sum of pairwise minimums of two sequences: max-lists from the left and right respectively:

```hs
boxes :: (Num x, Ord x) => [x] -> x
boxes = fmap sum <$> zipWith min . scanl1 max <*> tail . scanr1 max
```

The first `fmap` is needed because both `<$>` and `<*>` are `infixl 4`; we could equivalently do it with parentheses as `sum <$> (zipWith min . scanl1 max <*> tail . scanr1 max)`, or you could write it in non-pointfree style of course.

**Edit reason**: I had assumed that the challenge was "fill each column until it would otherwise spill over a partition" not "fill it uniformly until it reaches a steady state where the amount you're adding is also spilling out the sides," which is apparently what is intended. But it's no big deal: to figure out when something ever spills to infinity in some direction, just calculate the max list in that direction and you can fill up to that value. Still a one-liner, though.

## Longer Pseudocode

So if you don't know Haskell probably all of those idioms are a little foreign. Let me try to break this down with something more Pythonic for `scanl1 max` as a "generator":

```py
def accumulateMax(gen):
    accumulator = None
    for x in gen:
        accumulator = x if accumulator == None else max(accumulator, x)
        yield accumulator

def boxes(ints): # start : [2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2]
    maxesLeft = accumulateMax(ints) # [2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
    maxesRight = reverse(accumulateMax(reverse(ints)) # [4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    sum = 0
    # this list is [(2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 2)]
    for (x, y) in zip(maxesLeft, tail(maxesRight)):
        sum += min(x, y)
    # so the sum of pairwise minima is 2 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 13.
    return sum
```

In other words we pass through the list both storing the maximum element to the right and the maximum element to the left for each position. That solves the problem because `maxesLeft` tells you "if the water level goes higher than this, then water will fall off to the left," and likewise for `maxesRight`.

Comment: "Sum of pairwise minimums of elements" is not correct!

Comment: @PTDS fixed. still boring.

Answer (score 0):

You robbed yourself of a chance to have this question answered by not making it clear from the get-go. Let me add some illustration to it:

```
Case 1:
p = {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2}; total = 13

    |
    | x |
| x | x | x | x   x   x |
| x | x | x | x | x | x |


Case 2:
p = {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2}; total = 18

        |
    | x | x   x   x |       
| x | x | x | x   x | x | x |   
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
```

---

**Solution:** start scanning the partitions from left to right. As you stop at a partition (call this `start`), scan from the right to left to check if the range is sub-divided by a taller partition (call it `end`). If not, keep advancing `end` to the left until no more sub-division. The water level is the lower of `p[start]` and `p[end]`.

Pseudo-code (with a slight Swift flavor as that's what I used):

```
// The range from start to end is divided if there is
// a partition taller than the water level in-between
func isDivided(start, end) -> Bool {
    waterLevel = min(p[start], p[end])

    for i = end - 1; i > start; i-- {
        if p[i] > waterLevel {
            return true
        }
    }    
    return false
}

start  = 0
volume = 0
while start < n - 1 {
    end = n - 1
    while isDivided(start, end) {
        end--
    }

    waterLevel = min(p[start], p[end])
    volume += waterLevel * (end - start)
    print("segment = \(start) - \(end), water level = \(waterLevel)")
}

print("volume = \(volume)")
```

I assume that the `p` array is indexed from `0...(n-1)`

---

**Examples:**

When `p = {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2}`, it gives the following output:

```
segment = 0 - 1, water level = 2
segment = 1 - 2, water level = 3
segment = 2 - 6, water level = 2
volume = 13
```

When `p = {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2}`, this is returned:

```
segment = 0 - 1, water level = 2
segment = 1 - 2, water level = 3
segment = 2 - 5, water level = 3
segment = 5 - 7, water level = 2
volume = 18
```